# WebDriver/ 'null' is not an object

Tags: selenium, safari, webdriver

I use `webdriver` and `grid2`. I run a hub in a `MAC` machine, and use the `Safari` browser.

When I run my test, it gives the next exception, when I search for an element by ID:

Exception

```
16:12:52: [Exception]: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'a.split') (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 26 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:32:38'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.2', java.version: '1.6.0_37'
Session ID: null
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities [{platform=MAC, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, secureSsl=true, browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, version=6.0.1}]
Command duration or timeout: 4.48 seconds
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:23:22'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_09'
Session ID: 78100ca3-4843-4a59-8eb6-716b2262e119
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=MAC, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, secureSsl=true, browserName=safari, webdriver.remote.sessionid=78100ca3-4843-4a59-8eb6-716b2262e119, takesScreenshot=true, version=6.0.1}]
```

The test is passed in other OS and other browser (Windows 7 with IE9/Firefox/Chrome, and Windows XP with FireFox and chrome)

Comment: Can you post the code which is erroring?

Comment: @vincebowdren:

 @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "desc")
 private WebElement inputDescription;

and in the function:
inputDescription.sendKeys(description);

Answer (score 0):

I can see several possibilities of this issue, maybe the basic ones:

1)  `@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "desc")`
Are you sure that 'desc' is correct id of searching element? Btw, you can shorten the FindBy to `@FindBy(id = "desc")`

2) Do you init this element ?

```
public UrClass(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);         
    }
```

3) If yes, are you able to invoke any other action on the given element?